# JQuery Mobile: Button area not fully clickable, only left part of button triggers action

Tags: jquery, forms, mobile, button

I have a form with several buttons, I use the first div to make the form wider (width:330px) - appearently the everything is adjusted to this width but the clickable area:

```
<div data-role="popup" id="popupLogin" data-theme="a" class="ui-corner-all" style="width:330px">
    <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">Abbrechen</a>
<form id="navigation" name="navigation" onsubmit="return startNav()">
    <div style="padding:15px 20px;">
    <h3 class="h2">Ziel dieser Fahrt:</h3>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" id="action" />
    <label for="un" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Stra&szlig;e (Ziel):</label>
    <input name="strasse" id="strasse" value="" placeholder="Stra&szlig;e, Gesch&auml;ft, Einrichtung" data-theme="c" type="text">
    <label for="pw" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Stadt (Ziel):</label>
    <input name="stadt" id="stadt" value="" placeholder="Stadt oder Ortsbezeichnung" data-theme="c" type="text">
    <button type="submit" id="homenav" name="homenav" value="home" data-theme="a" data-icon="myapp-homenav" data-role="button">nach Hause</button>
    <button type="submit" id="worknav" name="worknav" value="work" data-theme="a" data-icon="myapp-worknav" data-role="button">zur Arbeit</button>
    <button type="submit" id="navnav" name="navnav" data-theme="a" value="input" data-icon="myapp-navnav" data-role="button">Navigation starten</button>
</div>
  </form>
</div>
```

The form renders fine, but the buttons are not triggering the click event on their full length. Clicking the right part, the button toggels but does not submit the form.

In fact on clicking it shows only a part stretching from left border to about 70% of the button. Clicking in this area does submit the form.

[image: Buttons submit area not stretching button width]

Picture: http://oi49.tinypic.com/214qoec.jpg

Comment: Have you looked to see if another css style is overriding the default jquery css width?  This was happening to me because I was using twitter bootstrap which was setting the width to auto instead of 100%.

Comment: Thanks for this hint! Solved my Problem. A second css was overriding the default jquery css ...